# How can I send an html message using Java mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Ive been sending plaintest email from Java no problem but Im now trying to send a html one as follows:

```
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(Email.getSession());
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("support@jthink.net"));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to, true));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setContent(msg, "text/html");
        message.setText(msg);
        message.saveChanges();
        Transport.send(message);
```

However when I receive it in my client it receives it as a plain text email, i.e it shows all the html tags instead of them being used for formatting, and I have checked the email header and it does say

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

in the mail header

but why because I pass "text/html" to the setContent() method and that seems to be the only thing you have to do.

Comment: Have you tried: message.setContent(msg, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

Comment: you can also use message.addPart(msg,"text/html;charset=UTF-8");
As long is within <html></html> tags it works.

Comment: Have you seen [the advice on the Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html#sendhtml)?

Comment: Yes I tried  message.setContent(msg, "text/html; charset=utf-8"); first and it didn't work to mak esure Ive tried it again and it still doesnt work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
message.setText(msg, "utf-8", "html");
```

or

```
message.setContent(msg, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

Avoid the **setText** method, you only need setContent.

It should be like this:

```
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(Email.getSession()); 
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("support@jthink.net"));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to, true));
message.setSubject(subject);
message.setContent(msg, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
message.saveChanges();
Transport.send(message);
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: First you're calling setContent method, and then setText. I think this is the problem. You only need one method as I wrote in my post, try avoiding your setText method and keep message.setContent(msg, "text/html; charset=utf-8");

Comment: I have edited my post, try something like this. I am not testing it, but I think it should be in that way. Hope it works for you!

Comment: setText overrides what setContent does.  Just use the setText method that allows you to specify the charset and text type.  That lets JavaMail format the Content-Type header for you, taking care of quoting, etc.

Comment: Doh, thanks guys until @BillShannon comment I was totally failing to see that I had the setText() method in there as well as setContent(), removing setText() fixed the issue.